# Is before_action outside the scope of private methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the controller:

`before_action { |controller| controller.param_policy(action_name) }`.

Also in the same controller is the `param_policy` method. Under `private`. Why is rails complaining with:

```
private method `param_policy' called for #<SomeController:0x007fc80196bc40>
```

The code:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action { |controller| controller.param_policy(action_name) }

  private

  def param_policy(action_name)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Is `before_action` outside the scope of `private` methods?

Comment: Actually what it seems is you are calling the `param_policy` on an instance of the controller which cannot call the private method. Instead using `before_action :param_policy` would work.

Comment: Yeap this works! Feel free to leave it as an answer and I will mark it as such

Comment: Or you can make the method `protected`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax in rails 4 to append a callback to a controller is:

```
before_action :param_policy
```

In rails 3, it was `before_filter`. Seeing the error, it seems that you are calling `param_policy` on an instance of class `SomeController`, which cannot call the private method, as it is a basic OOPS concept.